# Display used by screen in utmp

Tags: x11, gnu-screen, display, who

The X window system in a desktop Linux (where just one physical monitor is used) usually uses display 0, screen 0.
The output of `who` in Ubuntu 14.04 is

```
user1   :0           2016-06-15 14:25 (:0)
```

where `:0` is the abbreviation for `:0.0` (`:display.screen`). Here I logged in only from the GUI.

Then I opened a terminal emulator; I ran `screen` and I created two different windows (each of them simply contained `bash`). The resulting output of `who` was:

```
user1   :0           2016-06-15 14:25 (:0)
user1   pts/1        2016-06-15 14:26 (:0)
user1   pts/11       2016-06-15 16:31 (:0:S.0)
user1   pts/11       2016-06-15 16:31 (:0:S.1)
```

Why is this syntax used? It seems to be `:display:display.screen`.
Does `screen` emulate another display inside the physical display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to the text at the end of the line.  That is written by `screen` to indicate which pseudo-terminal connection it is using, as well as which window-number `screen` has assigned to it.  [Comments](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/utmp.c#n236) in the code indicate what it does:

```
/* 
 * Construct a utmp entry for window wi. 
 * the hostname field reflects what we know about the user (display) 
 * location. If d_loginhost is not set, then he is local and we write 
 * down the name of his terminal line; else he is remote and we keep 
 * the hostname here. The letter S and the window id will be appended. 
 * A saved utmp entry in wi->w_savut serves as a template, usually. 
 */
```

[and later](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/utmp.c#n302)

```
      /* 
       * we want to set our ut_host field to something like 
       * ":ttyhf:s.0" or 
       * "faui45:s.0" or 
       * "132.199.81.4:s.0" (even this may hurt..), but not 
       * "faui45.informati"......:s.0 
       * HPUX uses host:0.0, so chop at "." and ":" (Eric Backus) 
       */
```

concluding with the actual code which you might recognize:

```
    sprintf(host + strlen(host), ":S.%d", win->w_number);

    strncpy(u.ut_host, host, sizeof(u.ut_host));
```

which stores the string in the `ut_host` member of the utmp/utmpx structure.

Further reading:

- [utmp, wtmp - login records](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html)
- [who - show who is logged on](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/who.1.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. So, basically it is `screen` which writes and decides this syntax for the utmp entries, not the X server. Is it right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.